# Before Android Activity resumes will it always call onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, activity-lifecycle

Will my `Android` `Activity` always call `onResume()` when it goes to the foreground?

Comment: If you're talking about an `Activity` then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, based on [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest to look at the Android Activity Life-cycle management.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

Answer (score 0):

The Activity Lifecycle always rest till onResume() method when the screens comes fully visible on the foreground otherwise it may stop at onStart() when the screen view is partially visible possibly blocked by a modal dialog.